# Asm insertion in naked function

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I have ubuntu 16.04, x86_64 arch, 4.15.0-39-generic kernel version.
GCC 8.1.0

I tried to rewrite this functions(from first post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/qHDCU73cEFc) from Intel dialect to AT&T. And I did not succeed.

```
namespace atomic {
  __declspec(naked)
  static void*
  ldptr_acq(void* volatile*) {
    _asm {
      MOV EAX, [ESP + 4]
      MOV EAX, [EAX]
      RET
    }
  }

  __declspec(naked)
  static void*
  stptr_rel(void* volatile*, void* const) {
    _asm {
      MOV ECX, [ESP + 4]
      MOV EAX, [ESP + 8]
      MOV [ECX], EAX
      RET
    }
  }
}
```

Then I wrote a simple program, to get the same pointer, which I pass inside. I installed GCC version 8.1 with supported naked attributes(https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html "The x86 port now supports the naked function attribute") for fuctions.
As far as I remember, this attribute tells the compiler not to create the prologue and epilog of the function, and I can take the parameters from the stack myself and return them.
Code:(don't work with segfault)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

  __attribute__ ((naked))
  int *get_num(int*) {
    __asm__  (
      "movl 4(%esp), %eax\n\t"
      "movl (%eax), %eax\n\t"
      "ret"
    );
  }

int main() {
    int *i =(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *i = 5;

    int *j = get_num(i);
    printf("%d\n", *j);

    free(i);
    return 0;
}
```

then I tried using 64bit registers:(don't work with segfault)

```
__asm__  (
  "movq 4(%rsp), %rax\n\t"
  "movq (%rax), %rax\n\t"
  "ret"
);
```

And only after I took the value out of rdi register - it all worked.

```
__asm__  (
  "movq %rdi, %rax\n\t"
  "ret"
);
```

Why did I fail to make the transfer through the stack register? I probably made a mistake. Please tell me where is my fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the x86-64 System V calling convention passes args in registers, not on the stack, unlike the old inefficient i386 System V calling convention.

You always have to write asm that matches the calling convention, if you're writing the whole function in asm, like with a `naked` function or a stand-along `.S` file.

GNU C extended asm allows you to use operands to specify the inputs to an asm statement, and the compiler will generate instructions to make that happen.  (I wouldn't recommend using it until you understand asm and how compilers turn C into asm with optimization enabled, though.)

---

Also note that `movq %rdi, %rax` implements `long *foo(long*p){return p;}` not `return *p`.  Perhaps you meant `mov (%rdi), %rax` to dereference the pointer arg?

---

**And BTW, you definitely don't need and shouldn't use inline asm for this.**  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm, and see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

In GNU C, you can cast a pointer to `volatile uint64_t*`.  Or you can use `__atomic_load_n (ptr, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)` to get basically everything you were getting from that asm, without the overhead of a function call or any of the cost for the optimizer at the call-site of having all the call-clobbered registers be clobbered.

You can use them on any object: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html  Unlike C++11 where you can only do atomic ops on a `std::atomic<T>`.

Comment: @Max: after reading the first part of your question more carefully, IDK why you're using inline asm for this at all.  You don't need inline asm and shouldn't use inline asm for it.

Comment: "mov (%rdi), %rax "   yes, my mistake.


In a post from Google, a reporter wrote that it could be rewritten into AT&T dialect. 
QUOTE " Also, it should be rather trivial to convert this over
to GCC and Linux. Alls you would need to do is create the atomic functions in AT&T inline assembler syntax."

And I was curious to try to do it.:-)

thank you for links

ps every time I start thinking that I know C, I go to the stackoverflow.

Comment: @Max: naked functions with basic asm is one way you can implement it, but it's pretty crap for efficiency.  GNU C Extended asm can inline.  like `asm("mov %1, %0" : "=r"(output) : "=m"(*ptr));`.  IMO you learn more about asm from looking at compiler *output*, though, than from fumbling around with inline asm.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](/q/38552116)

Comment: Oops, I mean `"m"(*ptr)` for the input operand, no `=`.

Comment: "IMO you learn more about asm from looking at compiler output"

I'll do it %)